# Angular - Usar Lazy loading a un modulo que tiene componentes diferentes usando la ruta del padre

Tags: angular, angular-router

Estoy tratando de cargar de forma diferida un módulo -> menu.module # MenuModule

```
 rutas constantes: Rutas = [
         {
            camino: '',
            loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
        }, {ruta: '**', loadChildren: './ menu.module # MenuModule'}];
```

MenuModule tiene otras rutas

```
rutas constantes: Rutas = [
    {ruta: 'hello', componente: HelloComponent, ruta de acceso: 'completo'},
{ruta: 'hello2', componente: Hello2Component, pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

Necesito que hello y hello2 sean como http://server/hello o http://server/hello2 pero siempre entra en Home por la coincidencia con ''.

No quiero poner esas rutas (Hello y hello2) en padre, ya que quiero que ambos usen un nuevo módulo y no quiero crear una nueva ruta para cada 'hello'.

¿Tienes alguna idea de cómo puedo resolver esto?

PD: Este es un ejemplo, el proyecto real tiene más rutas en el router hijo, por eso no quiero crear una nueva ruta para cada componente. Probé de usar matcher pero no funciona ya que UrlSegment siempre tiene longitud 0

Gracias

Comment: Hola. Ya pudiste resolverlo?. No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Lazy load requiere un modulo para cada subruta que quieras cargar (como lo estas haciendo) y mientras sigas dejando ` route: ''` para el home module siempre entrara directo a el.